# Show that $A\in \mathcal{B}(X_{2},X_{1}).$ and Compute the norm $\Vert A\Vert.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Please leave **some hint and comments** to the following Problem **not the whole solution**

> **Problem:** Let $X_{1}$ be the normed linear space $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ equipped with the norm $\Vert f\Vert_{1}=(\int_{0}^{1}\vert f(t)\vert)$,  $X_{2}$ be the normed linear space $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ equipped with the norm $\Vert f\Vert_{2}=(\int_{0}^{2}\vert f(t)\vert)$. Given $f\in X_{2},$ let $A(f(t))=tf(t).$
>   Show that $A\in \mathcal{B}(X_{2},X_{1}).$ and Compute the norm $\Vert A\Vert.$
>
> **What I have done:** 
>   $$\Vert A(f(t))\Vert_{1}=\int_{0}^{1}\vert tf(t)\vert dt\leq (\int_{0}^{1}t^{2}dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}(\int_{0}^{1}\vert f(t)\vert^{2}dt)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
>   $$=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\Vert f\Vert_{2}<\infty $$
>   So $A(f(t))\in X_{1}.$ And $\Vert A\Vert \leq  \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}. $
>
> *This completely seems logical to me but everything is fishy.* Because if I calculate $f(t)=\sqrt{3}t$, then I get $\Vert A(f(t))\Vert=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}. $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

With $f(t)=\sqrt{3} t$ you have $\| f\|_2=\sqrt{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=1$ and as you computed $\|A f\|_1=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ so:
$$\| A f\| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \|f\|_2$$ and there is no problem.

Comment: So I made a very inappropriate mistake. TNX.